# Where window array is set used in namespace.js in pimcore?

Tags: javascript, plugins, namespaces, pimcore

Below is code for `namespace.js`. Here set window array which has many objects in it. Now from where this window array has come. Where it is set.

```
/**
     * Pimcore
     *
     * This source file is available under two different licenses:
     * - GNU General Public License version 3 (GPLv3)
     * - Pimcore Enterprise License (PEL)
     * Full copyright and license information is available in
     * LICENSE.md which is distributed with this source code.
     *
     * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2009-2016 pimcore GmbH (http://www.pimcore.org)
     * @license    http://www.pimcore.org/license     GPLv3 and PEL
     */

    if (!pimcore) {
        var pimcore = {};
    }


    pimcore.registerNS = function(namespace) {
        var spaces = namespace.split(".");
        console.log(window);
        // create main space
        if (typeof window[spaces[0]] != "object") {
            window[spaces[0]] = {};
        }
        var currentLevel = window[spaces[0]];

        // create all subspaces
        for (var i = 1; i < (spaces.length - 1); i++) {
            if (typeof currentLevel[spaces[i]] != "object") {
                currentLevel[spaces[i]] = {};
            }
            currentLevel = currentLevel[spaces[i]];
        }
        return currentLevel;
    };
```

In this code where window is set?

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript is intended to be run in a Internet Browser *Window*. If you run a JavaScript in a Internet Browser, it provides several additional Application Programming Interfaces (API) - one of which is the [Window Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

Besides the fact, that your code snippet is from the Pimcore Sources, this question is not related to Pimcore at all.